# Determine the File System of a Network Path in .NET

Tags: .net, filesystems, ntfs, network-share

For one of my pojects, I wish to take advantage of [Alternate Data Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askcore/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs), which is a feature of the NTFS file system that you can read more about at the given link. Since the feature is unique to NTFS, I need to do a preliminary check to make sure the directory that I'm working in is using that file system.

If the directory is on a local drive I can use [`System.IO.DriveInfo.DriveFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.driveformat) to check the file system. However, if the directory is a network/UNC path such as `\\Computer\Folder\Subfolder` I can't use the `DriveFormat` class.

Is there any way I can find out the underlying file system for a network share? I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/driveinfo.cs,113) of the `DriveInfo` class's `DriveFormat` property, you can see it is making a native call to [GetVolumeInformationA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationa) in `kernel32.dll` to get the actual drive format.

Calling to this function with a network UNC path such as `\\Computer\Folder\` does give you the result that you want (include the trailing slash and do not include subfolders).  It's a bit of work to do the same pattern with the [dll import](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs,1114) and proper [error checking](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/__error.cs,200) in your own code, but it is possible!

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this yet, but I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work. Good call looking into the source code.